# Spring BindingResult in MVC Controller method

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, binding

Take this part of code for example

```
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String addUserFromForm(@Valid User user, BindingResult bindingResult){
    if(bindingResult.hasErrors()){
        return "users/edit";
    }
    userService.saveUser(user);
    return "redirect:/users/"+user.getName();
}
```

How does the controller's method knows about BindingResult object? Where's that object initialized and passed to the method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All the parameters passed to controller methods are initialized and filled by the spring-mvc dispatcher servlet.

The `User` object is instantiated and mapped to request parameters by a binder (`DataBinder` implementation). If there are problems, the `BindingResult` is filled with information about these problems and passed to your method.

Comment: thanks, it make sense, the same applies for BindingResult as for  HttpServletRequest and HttpServletResponse.